# Spark mongodb connector - Error MongoInputPartition

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pymongo

I'm trying to read data from mongodb running on spark inside kubernetes and I'm getting the following error:

```
22/10/04 17:28:28 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (10.244.1.109 executor 2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.read.MongoInputPartition
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:457)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The spark version in kubernetes is 3.1.1.
I'm able to run this connection locally in vscode, this error happens only when running inside the cluster.

driver package:

```
.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.4')
```

spark load:

```
df = spark.read.format("mongodb")\
        .option("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://user:password@host:port/&authSource=admin&tls=true")\
        .option("database", "dbname") \
        .option("collection","collection_name") \
        .load() 

df.show(10)
```

The error happens during the df.show() command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the assembly jar

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.12/3.0.1/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1-assembly.jar

In the spark conf:

```
.config("spark.jars", "mongo-spark-connector_2.12-3.0.1-assembly.jar")
```

Spark reading:

```
df = spark.read.format("mongo")\
        .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://user:password@host:port/database.collection?&authSource=admin&tls=true")\
        .load()
```